# MFP 7.1 - Send Bulk Messages (POST)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

The send Bulk message API does it have any kind of Message queue? If messages are send by greater numbers like 10k to 50k in a batch how does this service handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bulk message API in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 does not maintain a queue. It processes the messages and delivers them sequentially to relevant vendor (APNS/GCM/MPNS/...).